# Do a time diff between to tables mysql

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have a problem to make a time diff between to tables.

```
$date = "$year-01-11 00:00:00";
$test2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date. "first day of this month"));
$date = "$year-01-11 23:59:59";
$test = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date. "first day of next month"));
$test = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($test. "-1day"));

$sql = "SELECT AVG(TO_SECONDS(dato2) - TO_SECONDS(dato3)) as avTime
FROM proservice WHERE dato3 >= '$test2' AND dato3 <= '$test' AND status_kode ='9' AND ind_kode != '7' AND ans != '1'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$timeDiff = mysql_result($res, 0, 'avTime');
$trt01 = $timeDiff/86400;  // 86400 seconds in one day
$trt01 = $trt01 * -1;
$trt01 = intval($trt01);
```

I use this one to make my time diff in the one table.

But I need do so I can see the time diff. between the first id in my table `proservice_rapport` form the column which have "`servicereport`" that is the same as proservice "ID" I need to get the time from "`dato`" on erye "id" form proservice the is between "`dato3 >= '$test2`' AND `dato3`" the make the time diff between the "`dato`" in `Proservice_rapport` and "`date3`" in Proservice.

Comment: It's hard to give a detailed answer without seeing the table columns, and your English is also not clear. But I think you just need to write a `JOIN` between the two tables.